# JavaScript code not working with multiple HTML elements

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, html

I've build myself a sign input on my website inside a modal popup. The problem is that I can have an unknown amount of modals generated in a foreach within PHP. Because of this my JavaScript code don't works anymore. Do you have any idea how I can improve my function to make it workable for a undefined amount of signature modals?

```js
var signaturePad;
jQuery(document).ready(function () {
    jQuery(document).on('opened', '#sign-modal', function () {
        var signaturePadCanvas = document.querySelector('.signature-pad-canvas');
        var parentWidth = jQuery(signaturePadCanvas).parent().outerWidth();
        signaturePadCanvas.setAttribute("width", parentWidth);
        signaturePad = new SignaturePad(signaturePadCanvas);
        jQuery('#clear-signature').click(function () {
            if (signaturePad) {
                signaturePad.clear();
            }
        });
    });
});
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/signature_pad@3.0.0-beta.3/dist/signature_pad.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/remodal@1.1.1/dist/remodal.min.js"></script>

<div id="sign-modal" class="remodal remodal remodal-is-initialized remodal-is-opened" data-remodal-id="sign-nda-modal-1234567889">
    <button data-remodal-action="close" class="remodal-close"></button>
    <h1>Hello</h1>
    <p>I am a random text</p>
    <div class="signature-pad-canvas-container">
        <div class="signature-pad-canvas-wrapper">
            <canvas class="signature-pad-canvas"></canvas>
        </div>
        <div class="clear-signature-wrapper">
            <span id="clear-signature">Delete</span>
        </div>
    </div>
    <br>
    <div class="remodal-buttons">
        <button data-remodal-action="cancel">Cancel</button>
        <button onclick="sign('123abc', '456cdf')">Sign</button>
    </div>
</div>
<div id="sign-modal" class="remodal remodal remodal-is-initialized remodal-is-opened" data-remodal-id="sign-nda-modal-9876543">
    <button data-remodal-action="close" class="remodal-close"></button>
    <h1>Hello</h1>
    <p>I am a random text</p>
    <div class="signature-pad-canvas-container">
        <div class="signature-pad-canvas-wrapper">
            <canvas class="signature-pad-canvas"></canvas>
        </div>
        <div class="clear-signature-wrapper">
            <span id="clear-signature">Delete</span>
        </div>
    </div>
    <br>
    <div class="remodal-buttons">
        <button data-remodal-action="cancel">Cancel</button>
        <button onclick="sign('764647gc', 'iuhiz78')">Sign</button>
    </div>
</div>
......
```

Comment: I recommend using a class instead of `id="sign-modal"`. Note that [IDs must be unique to the document](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTML/Global_attributes/id).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The reason why your modals have stopped working is because each modal you create is created with the same `id`.

This means that when you access the element with DOM, only the first element would be returned. Using a `class` is not the best idea as you lose the ability to target specific elements without looping.

The best solution in my opinion is to dynamically generate the `id` as you create your modals. This means you could have something like `sign-modal-1`, `sign-modal-2` etc for each modal you create.

Then, in JQuery, you target elements with ID's that get opened, that begin with `sign-modal`, i.e. using the JQuery attribute selector.

**JQuery Attribute Selector**:
https://api.jquery.com/attribute-starts-with-selector/

Comment: So you mean I should define the gloabl JS var in PHP within my loop and give the modal a random  id which is used during  open to target the right one?

Comment: Yes, the ID must always be unique, as it only references a single DOM element on the page. Having it random might not be the best idea, usually you would correspond it to the loop index, but as long as it's unique and targetable, it should be fine.

Comment: Alright, so I'm generating now the global variable name in the foreach. Now I've tried to add the random number defined in a custom data attribute to the global var init but i don't works: signaturePad + targetId = new SignaturePad(signaturePadCanvas); Any idea how I can add the id to the gloabl?

Comment: Use the attribute selector to get the corresponding modal that is linked, and after you have the modal, use the DOM tree to find the signaturePadCanvas. As all your modals are the same structure, they’ll be in the same position in the tree, the only thing you have to dynamically check for is which modal was clicked

Comment: But I think I need to define an own global variable signaturePad<random_numer> for each modal because it can't work otherwise. Or not? :S